# I am getting a very low theta value (~9%) when performing LDA in R, is this typical?

Tags: r, topic-models

I have performed LDA using the topicmodels package in R. When I was inspecting my theta values for each document in the corpus (~450,000 documents), I noticed that the average max theta, or in other words, the average highest probability that the document is in a certain topic, was ~9%. This seems very low, but I am unable to find any literature that would give me an idea of what it should be around.

In case I am doing something else wrong, here are the parameters I am using:

```
burnin <- 1000
iter <- 1000
keep <- 10
k<-100 
models <- LDA(dtm2, k, method = "Gibbs", control = list(burnin = burnin,        
iter = iter, keep = keep))

phi <- posterior(models)$terms %>% as.matrix
theta <- posterior(models)$topics %>% as.matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

You should decrease the value of alpha. By default, the alpha value is 50/k where k is the number of topics.

When you decrease the alpha value, the probability of a document being represented by fewer topics increases.